# Is there any way to bypass the enchantment limit in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The maximum enchantment limit (with commands/NBT) is 255 on version 1.19.2. I was wondering if somehow I could bypass that?

I saw an answer saying you need to edit the code, how do I need to edit the code?

Comment: Could you link to that answer that said you needed to edit the code? It may give some context that would be helpful.

Comment: The easiest way may be to use a mod.

Comment: @Spevacus i lost it

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use-case, you might get away with the [`/enchant`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/enchant) command. On Java Edition, the level can be any integer between `0` and `2147483647`.

The weakness of this approach is that it targets a player, who would need to be holding the item in their hand to receive the enchantment. This may or may not affect you.

If you need to use `/give`, you may need to create a mod and add a new command that allows greater enchantment levels. I recommend learning [Forge](https://files.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/). The Forge team maintains a good [tutorial](https://docs.minecraftforge.net/en/1.19.x/gettingstarted/) to teach you how to create basic mods. It's not a Java tutorial though, so if you don't know how to program, you may need to start elsewhere. If you have a specific question about mod creation, that would be better suited as a different question.

---

It looks like the changes to `/give` happened in 1.17. According to the [history section](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#History) of the format page, 1.17 was when it was clamped to `255`.

Comment: If my answer is low quality or not helpful, simply downvoting does not communicate what the problem is. A comment should be left explaining how the answer could be improved.

Comment: How should I edit the code? I already have an advanced Forge tutorial on [Udemy](http://udemy.com)

Comment: @berriz I think that would be a question better suited for the Forge message board or possibly StackOverflow. I don't have any experience with creating mods. I'm surprised the course didn't give you any detail. Although if you successfully completed the course, then you should at least know how to get started. Side point, are you sure that /enchant will not work for you? Making a mod is a substantial undertaking. You will also need to continuously update it for new versions of the game if you want to keep using it.

Comment: the /enchant command allows survival levels, so i cant use /enchant to bypass